# Why is deleting a function necessary when you're defining customization point object?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer, c++20, customization-point

From libstdc++ `<concepts>` header:

```
  namespace ranges
  {
    namespace __cust_swap
    {
      template<typename _Tp> void swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) = delete;
```

From MS-STL `<concepts>` header:

```
namespace ranges {
    namespace _Swap {
        template <class _Ty>
        void swap(_Ty&, _Ty&) = delete;
```

I've never encountered `= delete;` outside the context where you want to prohibit the call to copy/move assignment/ctor.

I was curious if this was necessary, so I've commented out the `= delete;` part from the library like this:

```
// template<typename _Tp> void swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) = delete;
```

to see if the following test case compiles.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

struct dummy {
    friend void swap(dummy& a, dummy& b) {
        std::cout << "ADL" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a{};
    int b{};
    dummy c{};
    dummy d{};
    std::ranges::swap(a, b);
    std::ranges::swap(c, d); // Ok. Prints "ADL" on console.
}
```

Not only it compiles, it seems to behave well by calling user defined `swap` for `struct dummy`. So I'm wondering,

1. What does  `template<typename _Tp> void swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) = delete;` exactly do in this context?
2. On what occasion does this break without  `template<typename _Tp> void swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) = delete;`?

Comment: _What does  template<typename _Tp> void swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) = delete; exactly do in this context?_ [I've found this :/](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/customization.point.object#6.sentence-2)

Comment: Note that the `=delete` idiom can also be used to hide a non-virtual inherited function. (That's not what is happening here, but it's another use beyond deleting any implicitly-defined constructor or assignment operator.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR: It's there to keep from calling `std::swap`.

This is actually an explicit requirement of [the `ranges::swap` customization point](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/concept.swappable#2.1):

> `S` is `(void)swap(E1, E2)` if `E1` or `E2` has class or enumeration type ([basic.compound]) and that expression is valid, with overload resolution performed in a context that includes this definition:
>
> ```
>  template<class T>
>   void swap(T&, T&) = delete;
> ```

So what does this do? To understand the point of this, we have to remember that the `ranges` namespace is actually the `std::ranges` namespace. That's important because a lot of stuff lives in the `std` namespace. Including this, declared in `<utility>`:

```
template< class T >
void swap( T& a, T& b );
```

There's probably a `constexpr` and `noexcept` on there somewhere, but that's not relevant for our needs.

`std::ranges::swap`, as a customization point, has a specific way it wants you to customize it. It wants you to provide a `swap` function that can be found via argument-dependent lookup. Which means that `ranges::swap` is going to find your swap function by doing this: `swap(E1, E2)`.

That's fine, except for one problem: `std::swap` exists. In the pre-C++20 days, one valid way of making a type swappable was to provide a specialization for the `std::swap` template. So if you called `std::swap` directly to swap something, your specializations would be picked up and used.

`ranges::swap` does *not* want to use those. It has one customization mechanism, and it wants you to very definitely use that mechanism, not template specialization of `std::swap`.

However, because `std::ranges::swap` lives in the `std` namespace, unqualified calls to `swap(E1, E2)` can find `std::swap`. To avoid finding and using this overload, it poisons the overload by making visible a version that is `= delete`d. So if you don't provide an ADL-visible `swap` for your type, you get a hard error. A proper customization is also required to be more specialized (or more constrained) than the `std::swap` version, so that it can be considered a better overload match.

Note that `ranges::begin/end` and similar functions have similar wording to shut down similar problems with similarly named `std::` functions.

Comment: Lookup inside the CPO is never affected by using-declarations at the point of use.

Comment: @T.C.: I made a test program to investigate this, but I didn't actually see what happened if I took out the `using` declaration. So you're right; the reason it's there is still similar to what I said, but different. It's to keep from calling `std::swap` directly because `std::swap` is in the same namespace as `std::ranges::swap` and is therefore visible to it. I've edited the answer to correct it.

Comment: The implementation could perform the lookup from somewhere (ugly) outside of `std`; it’s more `::swap` that’s being avoided.

Answer (score 9):

There were two motivations for the poison pill overloads, most of which don't actually exist anymore but we still have them anyway.

#### swap / iter_swap

As described in [P0370](https://wg21.link/p0370):

> The Ranges TS has another customization point problem that N4381 does not cover: an implementation of the Ranges TS needs to co-exist alongside an implementation of the standard library. There’s little benefit to providing customization points with strong semantic constraints if ADL can result in calls to the customization points of the same name in namespace std. For example, consider the definition of the single-type Swappable concept:
>
> ```
> namespace std { namespace experimental { namespace ranges { inline namespace v1 {
>   template <class T>
>   concept bool Swappable() {
>     return requires(T&& t, T&& u) {
>       (void)swap(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<T>(u));
>     };
>   }
> }}}}
> ```
>
> unqualified name lookup for the name swap could find the unconstrained swap in namespace std either directly - it’s only a couple of hops up the namespace hierarchy - or via ADL if `std` is an associated namespace of `T` or `U`. If `std::swap` is unconstrained, the concept is “satisfied” for all types, and effectively useless. The Ranges TS deals with this problem by requiring changes to std::swap, a practice which has historically been forbidden for TSs. Applying similar constraints to all of the customization points defined in the TS by modifying the definitions in namespace std is an unsatisfactory solution, if not an altogether untenable.

The Range TS was built on C++14, where `std::swap` was unconstrained (`std::swap` didn't become constrained until [P0185](https://wg21.link/p0185) was adopted for C++17), so it was important to make sure that `Swappable` didn't just trivially resolve to true for any type that had `std` as an associated namespace.

But now `std::swap` is constrained, so there's no need for the `swap` poison pill.

However, `std::iter_swap` is still unconstrained, so there *is* a need for that poison pill. *However*, that one could easily become constrained and then we would again have no need for a poison pill.

#### begin / end

As described in [P0970](https://wg21.link/p0970):

> For the sake of compatibility with `std::begin` and ease of migration, `std::experimental::ranges::begin` accepted rvalues and treated them the same as const lvalues. This behavior was deprecated because it is fundamentally unsound: any iterator returned by such an overload is highly likely to dangle after the full expression that contained the invocation ofbegin
>
> Another problem, and one that until recently seemed unrelated to the design of begin, was that algorithms that return iterators will wrap those iterators in std::experimental::ranges::dangling<>if the range passed to them is an rvalue. This ignores the fact that for some range types — P0789’s `subrange<>`, in particular — the iterator’s validity does not depend on the range’s lifetime at all. In the case where a prvalue `subrange<>` is passed to an algorithm, returning a wrapped iterator is totally unnecessary.
>
> [...]
>
> We recognized that by removing the deprecated default support for rvalues from the range access customization points, we made design space for range authors to opt-in to this behavior for their range types, thereby communicating to the algorithms that an iterator can safely outlive its range type. This eliminates the need for `dangling` when passing an rvalue `subrange`, an important usage scenario.

The paper went on to propose a design for safe invocation of `begin` on rvalues as a non-member function that takes, specifically, an rvalue. The existence of the:

```
template <class T>
void begin(T&&) = delete;
```

overload:

> gives `std2::begin` the property that, for some rvalue expression `E` of type `T`, the expression `std2::begin(E)` will not compile unless there is a free function `begin` findable by ADL that specifically accepts rvalues of type `T`, and that overload is prefered by partial ordering over the general `void begin(T&&)` “poison pill” overload.

For example, this would allow us to properly reject invoking `ranges::begin` on an rvalue of type `std::vector<int>`, even though the non-member `std::begin(const C&)` would be found by ADL.

But this paper also says:

> The author believed that to fix the problem with `subrange` and `dangling` would require the addition of a new trait to give the authors of range types a way to say whether its iterators can safely outlive the range. That felt like a hack, and that feeling was reinforced by the author’s inability to pick a name for such a trait that was sufficiently succint and clear.

Since then, this functionality has become checked by a trait - which was first called `enable_safe_range` ([P1858](https://wg21.link/p1858)) and is now called `enable_borrowed_range` ([LWG3379](https://wg21.link/lwg3379)). So again, the poison pill here is no longer necessary.